# How to use a recent GCC with Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

Apple completely removed whatever GCC support they used to have. Is there any way to use a recent GCC (say 4.8) with Xcode 5? In other words, to use GCC in place of LLVM within Xcode.

Comment: You will need to write an xcode plugin to support a different compiler, and it's probably a bit of work to accomplish it (I don't know, I've not written one but there are answers related to earlier releases of Xcode involving this work).

Comment: You could try to overwrite the `CC` flag in Xcode, as described under (2) in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261612/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-newer-version-of-llvm-and-use-it-with-xcode/16265711#16265711). The problem is that GCC has a different interface than Clang, so it doesn't understand all the flags Xcode sets by default. I couldn't make it work for an iOS template app, but it may work if you don't use a template or no Objective-C at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

install GCC 4.8 into Xcode 4.5, Xcode 4.6, Xcode 5.0:

for people who have not install GCC 4.8:

install the new version of home-brew

you can find the method how to install on the Internet

update your brew to the latest version (`$brew update`)

1.`brew install gcc48 --enable-all-languages`

(may should install mpc, mpfr and gmp through brew, http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/)

2.`$brew link gcc48`

3.backup g++,gpp,c++,cpp,c++ in `/usr/bin/`

4.[optional step]:

alias  g++-4.8,gpp-4.8,c++-4.8,cpp-4.8,c++-4.8

from `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/g++`

to `/usr/bin/`

**[above 4 steps for the developer who have not install gcc]**

5.make plugin

1)download  [a plugin of GCC 4.5 for Xcode](https://code.google.com/p/xcode-gcc-plugin/downloads/detail?name=GCC%204.5.xcplugin.zip&can=2&q=)

2)change every "4.5" to "4.8", "4_5" to "4_8", the file names, the file contents,

except "com.apple.compilers.gcc.headers.4_2” in the file `GCC 4.5.xcspec`.

you can remain contents in `English.lproj` unchanged, and delete `Japanese.lproj`.

3)in file `GCC 4.8.xcspec`

(hope you have already change the file name of `GCC 4.5.xcspec` to `GCC 4.8.xcspec`)

change `ExecPath = "...”;`

to `ExecPath = "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8"`

or `ExecPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/gcc-4.8"` (for the people who install gcc-4.8 by brew)

4)delete “-Wshorten-64-to-32” part in file `GCC 4.8.xcspec`

```
{
    Name = "GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION";
    Type = Boolean;
    DefaultValue = NO;
    CommandLineArgs = {
        YES = (
            "-Wshorten-64-to-32",
        );
        NO = ();
    };
    AppearsAfter = "GCC_WARN_PROTOTYPE_CONVERSION";
    Category = Warnings;
    CommonOption = NO;
    DisplayName = "Implicit Conversion to 32 Bit Type";
    Description = "Warn if a value is implicitly converted from a 64 bit type to a 32 bit type.
    [GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION, -Wshorten-64-to-32]";
}
```

6.put edited `GCC 4.8.xcplugin` into

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Plugins/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/`

7.reopen Xcode.

Now, the new plugin has already prepared for you. You can see your new GCC compiler plugin in the  "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" of "Build Settings" of your project

8.change Build Settings in Xcode project

1)In the `project` and `target` settings in Xcode

change "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to "GCC 4.8"

2)In the `project` settings

delete “CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" row

Comment: In addition to this, I had to make sure my binaries would link against the libstdc++ libraries in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/gcc/lib, i.e., I had to set the library path for the linker with -L /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/gcc/lib instead of -L /usr/lib.

Comment: I tried this on XCode 5.0.2 and the GCC 4.8.2 compiler is not shown in the list of compilers. I also tried it with XCode 3 and it did show up there. Maybe XCode 5.0.2 broke something.

Comment: @Halt, for me GCC shows up in the list of compilers. However I get an error about the "-Wmost" flag which is Clang this, but I cannot get rid of it

Comment: @frogcjn Did you guys try to apply this to xcode 5.1?

Comment: @frogcjn In XCode 5.1 you get a warning indicating 'Invalid C/C++' compiler in target followed by many errors reading Unsupported compiler '4.8' selected for architecture. Have tried adding  <key>DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs</key>
<string>A2E4D43F-41F4-4FB9-BB94-7177011C9AED</string> to the plug-in's Info.plist to no avail.

Comment: Is there a path where to put the .xcplugin that doesn't belong to the Xcode package? Some path down in ~/Library for example...

Comment: Xcode 5.1.1 still emits `-stdlib=` even though you delete the row `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY`. The build will fail since that option is not recognized by GCC. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Thanks, btw I had to add the location of omp.h to the Header Search Paths... In my case it was at position: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.1.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/5.1.0/include

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the latest versions of gcc can link against Apple's libraries. You can install newer versions of gcc, llvm (and clang), and a lot of other unix applications with Homebrew. Check it out [here](http://brew.sh/).