# OS X Yosemite 10.10, Xcode 6 and GCC 4.9 from port/homebrew

Tags: xcode, gcc, osx-yosemite

There are plenty of postings about getting a GCC 4.x into Xcode <= 5 on OS X <= 10.9. However, did anybody get it to work with the most recent Xcode on Yosemite?

I followed this explanation

[How to use a recent GCC with Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061966/how-to-use-a-recent-gcc-with-xcode-5)

but got stuck with Xcode saying that

```
GCC 4.9 is not compatible with the OS X 10.10 SDK (file Tests.cpp)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? Are you linking against the 10.10 SDK?

Comment: Well, I created a cmake project and ran `cmake -GXcode .`
to generate the project. Then in XCode, I select the GCC 4.9 and run "build". It does not even start compiling and stops at "Check dependencies". Btw, it does the same if I select the 10.9 SDK.

Comment: Ok, I'm one step further now... I used the files provided from here:
`https://github.com/vermosen/XCode_5_GCC_4_x` and now I'm at 
`gcc-mp-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmost'`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I'm there. So here's what I've done.

I took the plugins from [here](https://github.com/vermosen/XCode_5_GCC_4_x) and copied them over as indicated. Unfortunately there a a minor bug with the plugins I'm going to report to the author - the plugins have the same identifier, `gcc.4_2`. If you don't change the `CFBundleIdentifier`, you can't add both compilers as Xcode refuses to load two plugins with the same identifier. So I copied both plugins, but in the individual `Info.plist` files I changed

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apple.xcode.compilers.gcc.4_8</string>
```

for the 4.8 compiler and

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apple.xcode.compilers.gcc.4_9</string>
```

for the 4.9 compiler, beside fixing the `ExecPath` in the `*.xcspec` files to point to the corresponding `gcc` version in `/opt/local/bin`.

Then for the project I just select the right compiler and build it. One remaining thing is to remove the `-Wmost` flag from the `Other Warnings Flags` section in `GCC 4.9 - Warnings` section for the target to build.

So far, it works like a charm.