# Getting clang++5.0 to work on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

Clang 5 is finally [out there](http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) and I have eagerly downloaded it and tried the [coroutine example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dth1IO5q8Oe31ew2). Everything works nicely from command line and I am very happy about it.

Now, I would like Xcode to use clang5.0 to compile my code, so that I can play with coroutines and other experimental C++20 features with my favorite editor. Is it possible to do such a thing?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261612/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-newer-version-of-llvm-and-use-it-with-xcode/16265711) and, full of hope, I followed the instructions to replace `clang` and `libclang` within the Xcode package.

Xcode starts properly, however when I try to compile an hello world I get a lengthy linker error message that ends with `Cannot specify -o when generating multiple output fiels`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any guides out there to get this to work? Otherwise, I guess I'll just have to change IDE. Sigh.

Comment: 5.0.0 is already out for a half year, in a month we'll have 6.0.0

Comment: Well, I evidently have a very low clang-refresh rate :)